# Java Lower Bound Wildcard

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

How come the List in the main method below compiles?

```
class Breakfast {

}

class Drink extends Breakfast {

}

class Juice extends Drink {

}

class Food extends Breakfast {

}

class Bread extends Food {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object object = new Object();
    Drink drink = new Drink();
    Juice juice = new Juice();
    Bread bread = new Bread();

    List<? super Drink> firstList = Arrays.asList(object, drink, juice, bread);

    List<?> secondList = Arrays.asList(object, drink, juice, bread);

    List<? extends Drink> thirdList = Arrays.asList(drink, juice, bread); //DOESN'T COMPILE
}
```

Seeing as bread is not a superclass of Drink? What is the rule that allows the compilation of the first and second lists but not the third? And if so then what are the main differences between

```
<?>
```

and

```
<? super Drink>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the first one and the second one compile for the same reason: `?` is `Object` here, and `Object` is a super class of all of your list elements, so it works.

Comment: The difference between `<?>` and `<? super SomeType>` is when the topmost type of `SomeType` isn't `Object`.  For example, `Comparable<X>`.  `Object` does not extend `Comparable<X>`, so the highest class for a `Comparable<X>` will always be some class other than `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java compiler uses type inference to determine the type parameter for calls to generic methods such as `Arrays.asList`.  It determines the most specific type that can be derived as a supertype to all arguments.

For the first and second lists, there is an `Object` in the list, so `Object` is the inferred type parameter.  That works for `? super Drink`, because `? super Drink` is a lower bound that `Object` satisfies.  That also works for `?`, the unbounded wildcard, because `?` will match any inferred type parameter.  These will compile as long as you have different names for these two list variables.

For the third list (called `fourthList`?), you have a lower bound, `? extends Drink`, meaning that the type inferred must be a subtype of `Drink`, either `Drink` itself or a subclass.  Because `Breakfast` is the inferred type, and `Breakfast` is not a subtype of `Drink`, this is a compiler error.  If `Bread` were not in the list, then the inferred type would be `Drink` and this would compile.

Answer (score 0):

`extends` is an *upper* bound - that means that any instance specified must be no "higher" in the inheritance hierarchy than the specified type.

From your example, `? extends Drink` is the upper bound - so every object must then extend from `Drink` to be legally assigned into that list.

`super` is a *lower* bound - that means that any instance specified must be no "lower" in the inheritance hierarchy than the specified type.

From your example, `? super Drink` is the lower bound - so every object must then either be a type of `Drink` or a type of its ancestor - in this case, `Object`.

`?` is a wildcard - you actually don't *care* what type is in the collection if you're using it (since you can't get that information back).  By default, that results in `? extends Object`, and thus the upper bound rules apply (and are satisfied).